# Selenium Project Will not connect to Firefox

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading

Error:

> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect
>   to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
>   ons.xpi   DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on
>   onboarding@mozilla.org version 1.0
>   1531840048588 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for
>   /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/screenshots@mozilla.org.xpi
>   1531840048589 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on
>   screenshots@mozilla.org version 32.1.0
>   1531840048589 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for
>   /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/webcompat-reporter@mozilla.org.xpi
>   1531840048589 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on
>   webcompat-reporter@mozilla.org version 1.0.0
>   1531840048590 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for
>   /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
>   1531840048591 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on
>   webcompat@mozilla.org version 2.0
>   1531840048594 addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for
>   XPIProvider 1531840048594 addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished
>   startup: XPIProvider 1531840048594    addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting
>   provider: LightweightThemeManager
>   1531840048594 addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for
>   LightweightThemeManager 1531840048594 addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider
>   finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
>   1531840048594 addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
>   1531840048596 addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for
>   GMPProvider 1531840048596 addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished
>   startup: GMPProvider 1531840048597    addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting
>   provider: PluginProvider
>   1531840048597 addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for
>   PluginProvider 1531840048597  addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished
>   startup: PluginProvider 1531840048598 addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed
>   startup sequence 1531840049193    addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json
>   found. 2018-07-17 11:07:29.783 plugin-container[35125:1788379] ***
>   CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission
>   denied', port = 0x7127, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname' See
>   /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
>   1531840050170 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Ignoring file entry whose name is not a
>   valid add-on ID:
>   /var/folders/tl/89639tt516lfcbvtl60jn9d80000gq/T/anonymous6360919038492988020webdriver-profile/extensions/webdriver-staging
>   1531840050171 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on
>   activity-stream@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
>   1531840050171 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on aushelper@mozilla.org
>   in app-system-defaults 1531840050172  addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on
>   firefox@getpocket.com in app-system-defaults
>   1531840050172 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on
>   followonsearch@mozilla.com in app-system-defaults
>   1531840050172 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on
>   formautofill@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
>   1531840050173 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on onboarding@mozilla.org
>   in app-system-defaults 1531840050173  addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on
>   screenshots@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
>   1531840050174 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on
>   webcompat-reporter@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
>   1531840050175 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on webcompat@mozilla.org
>   in app-system-defaults 1531840050176  addons.xpi  DEBUG   Ignoring file
>   entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: /Library/Application
>   Support/Mozilla/Extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/.DC
>   1531840050176 addons.xpi  DEBUG   Existing add-on
>   web2pdfextension.17@acrobat.adobe.com in app-system-local
>   1531840050176 addons.xpi  DEBUG   getInstallState changed: false, state:
>   {} 2018-07-17 11:07:30.178 plugin-container[35126:1788400] ***
>   CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission
>   denied', port = 0x8b43, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname' See
>   /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes. JavaScript
>   error: resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm, line 2189:
>   TypeError: addon is null 2018-07-17 11:07:30.872
>   plugin-container[35127:1788513] *** CFMessagePort:
>   bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port =
>   0x6603, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname' See
>   /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.

```
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:112)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
at com.ctm.selenium.framework.selenium.browsers.FirefoxBrowser.setWebDriver(FirefoxBrowser.java:19)
at com.ctm.selenium.framework.selenium.browsers.Browser.<init>(Browser.java:48)
at com.ctm.selenium.framework.selenium.browsers.FirefoxBrowser.<init>(FirefoxBrowser.java:8)
at com.ctm.selenium.framework.selenium.browsers.BrowserFactory.getFirefoxBrowser(BrowserFactory.java:109)
at com.ctm.selenium.framework.selenium.browsers.BrowserFactory.getBrowser(BrowserFactory.java:89)
at com.ctm.selenium.framework.verification.junit.TestScript.setupTest(TestScript.java:92)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$CallableStatement.call(FailOnTimeout.java:298)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$CallableStatement.call(FailOnTimeout.java:292)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
```

## at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

How can I fix this?   Please if it can be as detailed as possible since I am new to Selenium ...

Answer (score 1):

please do try the below-listed method to invoke the driver.

```
private WebDriver firefoxDriver;

     private void initiateWebDriver() throws  Exception {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\PATH);
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
            capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
            firefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
            firefoxDriver.get("https://www.Desired_URL.com");

        }


  public WebDriver getWebDriver()  throws  Exception{

        if (null != firefoxDriver) {

            return firefoxDriver;
        }

        initiateWebDriver();
        return firefoxDriver;

    }
```

you may face this issue because of using an older version of gecko driver or not defining the pre-requested properties of the gecko driver prior initiation.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\PATH);
                DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
                capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
                firefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

use the method `getWebDriver()` to return the web driver to the test classes you prefer.